# How to retrieve just the loaded page's file name?

Tags: javascript

How can I check the loaded script (instead of the loaded script path) with JavaScript?

Example:

**Loaded script is Index.php**

- If I use window.location.pathname, I get `/folder1/folder2/Index.php`.
- If I use window.location.href, I get `http://www.website.com/folder1/folder2/Index.php`.
- If I use window.location.hostname, I get `www.website.com`.

What should I use to get only `Index.php`?

Answer (score 4):

You can split the path by `/` and then `pop()` the last item. E.g.

`window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Comment: Only work if the file have no parameter in the url with a '/', no ?

Comment: @Alexis `pathname` doesn't include querystrings/parameters.

Comment: @Alexis `pathname` does not include parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you manipulate the string that you have. You can use string methods to get the part after the last slash:

```
var page = window.location.pathname.substr(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```